# How to make shure there is a "~" between all bibtex formating data and user provided stuff?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, formatting

I want to make sure there is a ~ in something like

```
\newblock {\cyr\textnumero}~{11-1 (39)}.
```

instead of

```
\newblock {\cyr\textnumero} {11-1 (39)}.
```

So I have bibtex record alike this has in it a `number={11-1 (39)}` and it is in the end of the line:

[image]

As you can see it gets ugly and separated across lines. I want to eliminate possibilety of that. I wonder how to make bibtex put a "~" after all its formatting stuff such as "№", "C.", etc?

I use gost705 for formatting and `bibtex8 -B -8 %NAME%.aux` command to run bibtex supporting Russian. But I hope for a general answer.

Comment: the generated text (including the space that you want to change to `~` is specified in the bibliography style, oh I see gost705.bst is the bst style, will look..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text comes from

```
FUNCTION {bbl.nr} % { "\bblno{}" }
{
  curlanguage "english" =
    { "no." }
    { curlanguage "german" =
      { "H." }
      { curlanguage "russian" =
        { "{\cyr\textnumero}" }
        { "language is not defined: " language * warning$ "no" }
      if$
      }
    if$
    }
  i
f$
}
```

or the similar `bbl.nnr`

Searching for those strings show they occur in various places, but for instance

```
FUNCTION {format.number}
{ number empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.nr number tie.or.space.connect }
  if$
}
```

the function `tie.or.space.connect` adds a space or `~` according to the logic defined, but you want to replace that by always adding a `~` which is `"~" *`  so

```
FUNCTION {format.number}
{ number empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.nr "~" * number * }
  if$
}
```

and similar changes in any other uses.

If making such changes you should change the name of the bst file and the reference to it with the `\bibliographystyle` command in the latex document.